# Magento2 issue in pagination

Tags: pagination, magento2

I found an issue when we set pagination values for grid and list view in Magento2.

Go to **Admin: Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Storefront**

'Products per Page on Grid Default Value' is reflecting properly in grid view. But 'Products per Page on List Default Value' is not setting the pagination to that value in front end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might able to help out here. I had the same issue and after a bit of digging I found out what was wrong here.

The problem was within the 'vendor\magento\module-catalog\Helper\Product\ProductList.php' file.
In that class there is a constant called 'VIEW_MODE_LIST' which is set to 'view'.

if we take getAvailableLimit($mode) function as example we can see it returns a predefined array when ever the input does not match the constants.

So by simply changing the value of VIEW_MODE_LIST constant from 'view' to 'list' should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Magento Solved this issue in their latest version 2.1.0.